# Mail configuration for heartbeat, metricbeat and Elasticsearch 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am using heartbeat, metricbeat and elasticsearch 7.5 with kibana in our server to check the server status and to check the availability of the application. I want to get an email if an application or server is down or not responding. Is there any way to configure email for such or can I use curl to send an email to the developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [Watchers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html) to get notified about these events via E-Mail by using the [Email action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-email.html).

First, you need to implement a search query that the watcher will perform e.g. every 30 minutes of your particular indices. Then you have to define a condition that has to be met in order to execute the watcher-action (in this example the email action). Maybe the condition is *when a document exists in the heartbeat-index with field X having value Y* (e.g. checking if there was an http-code XXX).

So to sum it up:

Yes, you can configure that via Elasticsearch's Watcher-Feature. Please take a look at the documentation and the links I posted since it would be impossible to explain every detail here.

I hope I could help you.